# Difference between ListView.ItemTempate and ListViewItem.Template

Tags: wpf, listview

I have my `ListView`, which somehow works for me.

```
    <ListView x:Name="calendar" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                       AllowDrop="True"
                       SelectionMode="Single" 
                       MouseMove="kal_MouseMove" 
                       MouseUp="kal_MouseUp" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding CinnostiNaTyden}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCinnost}"
                       Datum="{Binding Datum}"
                       NasledujiciTydenCommand="{Binding NasledujiciTydenCommand}"
                       PredchoziTydenCommand="{Binding PredchoziTydenCommand}" 
                       ItemAddedCommand="{Binding ItemAddedCommand}" 
                       DragEnter="kal_DragEnter" 
                       DragOver="kal_DragOver"
                       Drop="kal_Drop" 
                       >
        <ListView.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
        </ListView.InputBindings>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Grid.Column="{Binding DatumCas, Converter={StaticResource ColumnConverter}}" 
                      Grid.Row="{Binding DatumCas, Converter={StaticResource RowConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Trvani, Converter={StaticResource RowSpanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Popis}" 
                           Padding="5,2,0,0" 
                           FontWeight="Bold" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <!--<Label Content="{Binding Trvani}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />-->
                    <Label Cursor="SizeNS" Height="5" Background="#00000000" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="LabelSpodni_MouseDown" Margin="0,0,0,-2"/>
                    <Label Cursor="SizeNS" Height="5" Background="#00000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="LabelHorni_MouseDown" Margin="0,-2,20,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <!--<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>-->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" 
                                    BorderThickness="2" 
                                    BorderBrush="DodgerBlue"
                                    Background="#CC4f9dea" 
                                    FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                                    Margin="0,0,22,2"  
                                    x:Name="Bd" 
                                    Padding="0,0,0,0" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                    <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                                            Opacity="0"
                                            Content="X" 
                                            Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                            Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            Height="20" Width="20"
                                            Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}"
                                            FontWeight="Bold" 
                                            FontFamily="Consolas" 
                                            Cursor="Hand"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#CC4f9dea" />
                                    <Setter Property="Tag" TargetName="btnClose" Value="Visible" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#cc96c0ea" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

Now look:

Firstly I set `ListView.ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And then I set this:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Name="Bd">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#CC4f9dea" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

So, firstly I set `ListView.ItemTemplate`, then I set `Template` for `TargetType` of `ListViewItem`. First is `DataTemplate`, second is `ControlTemplate`. But what is the difference between `ListView.ItemTemplate` and `ListViewItem.Template`?

Comment: why not read the docs about ListView.ItemTemplate and ListViewItem.Template?

Comment: Very kind of you Ash, I wish we had more kind-hearted answers like yours. For people new to programming: Don't hesitate to check the documentation. A good search engine will find the exact page you need, first try.

Comment: The [ListView.ItemTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate?view=netframework-4.8.1) can be found quite easily on DuckDuckGo search engine. The "ItemTemplate" is a Property of ListView. In contrast, the ListViewItem, like many other Views, has a [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/item-templates-listview) that you can access. It's not a property that can be set, it is its whole template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is the difference between `ListView.ItemTemplate` and `ListViewItem.Template`?

The `ItemTemplate` is a `DataTemplate` that is applied to each item in the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`. The root element of the `ItemTemplate` is implicitly wrapped in a `ListViewItem` container at runtime and this container has a default style with a default `ControlTemplate` that defines the default appearance of the container.

By defining a `ListViewItem` style that sets the `Template` property of the container, you are "overriding" this default template with your own custom one. That's why you for example won't get any highlighting when you select an item using the last custom `ControlTemplate` in your question.